# Extract list from data returned from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax call where I make call to a PHP via POST.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'CreateIcon.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType:'html',
      data: {iconname : newIconName},
      success: function(data) {
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
   });
```

My data here actually returns whole html / php code starting from html head / js / php everything. Out of this data I would like to display only lists inside this data which are present with ul tags
Is that possible to do?

Comment: It's possible, but it's better to write a new php script that will return you just what you need

Comment: The"html" returned is from your `CreateIcon.php` ?
Or you want to post data from the same page (CreateIcon.php posts to CreateIcon.php

Comment: Yes, html returned is from CreateIcon.php, Adding different php file is just duplication of code.

Comment: Just use `$(data).find('ul')` inside the success function ?

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially use the `.load()` method to just load a fragment of the document that you are interested in:

```
$('#target_node').load('CreateIcon.php ul')
```

Though if you just want the raw data and what to control how to display it on your page more easily, I would suggest just possible creating a new server-side script that gives you just what you need.  No reason to have the overhead of retrieving a full HTML document and parsing the pieces out of it that you want.

Comment: The new script would have dynamic images created by GD PHP, so the created images could be any number. How do I return the created image which can be displayed.

Comment: @user1821499 I am simply suggesting that instead of returning a complete HTML page, you can simply return the HTML fragments you are concerned with, which would give you the flexibility to use `.ajax()` method if you wanted. For example this might be best if you wanted to insert the data into various part of the parent document (rather then load in to one node in the parent document as done with `.load()`